# How to show error generated from $client = new SoapClient($myUrl),

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am using soap in php. I am Using very first time soap so i dont have enough knowledge abut this. 
I have Soap Code

```
 $client = new SoapClient("http://Url/services/webservices?wsdl",
    array('login' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'trace' => TRUE,
            'exceptions' => 1,
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2))
            or exit("Unable to create soap client!");
```

I call this soap request in SoapUI 5.0.0 software. 
In SoapUI, When I hit this soap service with blank username and password, its create some error.  on this line

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://Url/services/webservices?wsdl",
```

Error is :

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Bad credentials
Date: Tue, 06 Jan 2015 10:53:26 GMT
Server: Apache
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="realmNameForServices"
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=30, max=99
```

But On my php page, Its not showing in $client( when i m doint print_r($client)). 
Also i get Fetal error on this same  line , so next line is not executing.

Fetal error is showing.. Thats ok, as well as i have to show bad credentials error. Please suggest me how i can show this error on my php page. I need to show this error.

please excuse me for my poor english and my poor format of question.

Answer (score 1):

try with this :

```
try {  
   $client = new SoapClient("http://Url/services/webservices?wsdl",
                            array('login' => $username,
                                  'password' => $password,
                                  'trace' => TRUE,
                                  'exceptions' => 1,
                                  'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2))  
} catch (Exception $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer. I want to share it.

Answer was quite simple. i was not aware about this. I just change exceptions =>1 to exceptions =>0.
it start showing all the error generated from soap.